# sed - how to (not) match unmatched brackets

Tags: sed, regular-expression

How can I do my operation only on lines that close their brackets?

For example I want to change ".is" lines and add a bracket but not for lines with unclosed brackets.

so these are changed

```
this_thing.is 24  ->   (this_thing).is 24
that.is 50        ->   (that).is 50
a[23].is == 10    ->     a[23].is == 10
a.is true         ->   (this_thing).is 24
this_thing.is 24  ->   (this_thing).is 24
```

but these aren't:

```
this_thing.is (24
((that).is 50
(a[23].is == 10
a.is ( true
(this_thing.is 24
```

ideally also (not)

```
a{.is true
this_thing{.is 24
```

and (not)

```
a[.is true
this_thing[.is 24
```

I have a matcher with /.is/ but how to match unmatched brackets?

Comment: Depends on how "well" you need to do it. If you can only have a maximum of one level nesting you could write a complex(ish) regex for this, if you can have arbitrary levels of nesting, you'll need a scripting language.

Comment: max 1 level would be a start and might suffice for most cases.

Comment: I think there is errors in some of the first set of examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, if my regular expressions were approaching this level of complexity, I would just switch the whole operation to Perl. This one deals with an arbitrary number of open braces/parentheses/curly braces:

```
$ perl -ne '@open=/[\[({]/g; @close=/[)\]}]/g; 
             if($#close == $#open){s/(.+?)\.is/($1).is/} print' file
```

Or, more compact:

```
$ perl -pne 's/(.+?)\.is/($1).is/ if $#{/[\[({]/g} == $#{/[)\]}]/g}' file
```

Or more complete, this one can deal with cases like `[}` (but still fails on cases like `)(`):

```
  $ perl -pne '@osqb=/\[/g; @csqb=/\]/g; 
               @ocb=/\{/g; @ccb=/\}/g; 
               @op=/\(/g; @cp=/\)/g;
               if($#osqb == $#csqb && $#ocb==$#ccb && $#op == $#cp){
                    s/(.+?)\.is/($1).is/
               }' file
```

When run on your example, this will print

```
(this_thing).is 24
(that).is 50      
(a[23]).is == 10 
(a).is true      
(this_thing).is 24
this_thing.is (24
((that).is 50
(a[23].is == 10
a.is ( true
(this_thing.is 24
a{.is true
this_thing{.is 24
a[.is true
this_thing[.is 24
```

---

#### Explanation

- `perl -ne` : process the input file line by line (`-n`) and run the script given by `-e`.
- `@open=/[\[({]/g;` : find all opening glyphs and save the result in an array called `@open`.
- `@close=/[)\]}]/g;` : as above but for closing glyphs.
- `if($#close == $#open)` : if the number of opening glyphs is equal to the number of closing glyphs (if, in other words there are hanging parentheses etc)...
- `s/(.+?)\.is/($1).is/` : ...then replace the shortest string that ends in `.is` with itself enclosed within parentheses.
- The last `print` is outside the brackets and will be executed whether there was a substitution or not.

Comment: This is good, but has some bugs. example `[}` will match, so will `)(` etc.

Comment: @richard true, I am assuming those situations are not very likely, but yes, it will fail on them.

Comment: @richard thanks, I edited my answer with a more robust example. Still fails on `)(` but fixing that would make the whole thing too long.

Comment: +1 for "if my regular expressions were approaching this level of complexity, I would just switch the whole operation to Perl"

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on terdon's answer, you can use Perl to truly parse nested parenthetical constructs. Here's a regex that should do it:

```
$balanced_parens_grammar = qr/
  (?(DEFINE)                         # Define a grammar
    (?<BALANCED_PARENS> 
       \(                            # Opening paren
          (?:                        # Group without capturing
              (?&BALANCED_PARENS)    # Nested balanced parens
             |(?&BALANCED_BRACKETS)  # Nested balanced brackets
             |(?&BALANCED_CURLIES)   # Nested balanced curlies
             |[^)]*                  # Any non-closing paren
           )                         # End alternation
        \)                           # Closing paren
    )
    (?<BALANCED_BRACKETS> 
       \[                            # Opening bracket
          (?:                        # Group without capturing
              (?&BALANCED_PARENS)    # Nested balanced parens
             |(?&BALANCED_BRACKETS)  # Nested balanced brackets
             |(?&BALANCED_CURLIES)   # Nested balanced curlies
             |[^\]]*                 # Any non-closing bracket
           )                         # End alternation
        \]                           # Closing bracket
    )
    (?<BALANCED_CURLIES> 
       {                             # Opening curly
          (?:                        # Group without capturing
              (?&BALANCED_PARENS)    # Nested balanced parens
             |(?&BALANCED_BRACKETS)  # Nested balanced brackets
             |(?&BALANCED_CURLIES)   # Nested balanced curlies
             |[^}]*                  # Any non-closing curly
           )                         # End alternation
        }                            # Closing curly
    )
  )
  (?<BALANCED_ANY>
     (?:
         (?&BALANCED_PARENS)    
        |(?&BALANCED_BRACKETS)  
        |(?&BALANCED_CURLIES)   
     )
  )
/x;
```

Use it like so:

```
if( $line =~ m/
        ^
          [^()\[\]{}]*       # Any non-parenthetical punctuation
          (?&BALANCED_ANY)?  # Any balanced paren-types
          [^()\[\]{}]*
        $
        $balanced_parens_grammar/x){
    # Do your magic here
}
```

**Disclaimer**

Code is completely untested. Probably contains errors.

Comment: Wow, +1. I _really_ need to learn how `qr` works.

Comment: @terdon Thanks. FWIW, though, `qr//` has nothing to do with grammar definition: you could have written the whole thing inside the `m//` statement and it would've worked just as well. `qr//` pre-compiles a regex that is not expected to change later and since that's typical of a grammar, I used `qr//` here. I think it makes things more readable, too.

Comment: Ah, OK, I knew `qr` compiled a regex but have never used it. Grammar definition I know nothing about so I assumed the two were connected. Looks like a powerful tool.

Comment: @terdon Neither do I. I only recently learned about grammar definition in Perl so I can't wait to experiment :). If you think this is powerful try looking up Perl 6 rules!

Answer (score 1):

Sed uses regex, regular expressions are not powerful enough for this. Use gawk or some other tool that can do this.

There is a classification of grammars that show this: regular, context-free, etc. Matching parentheses cannot be done with a regular language. So you cannot do it reliably.